# Need help understanding this C Code (Array)

Tags: c, arrays

I need help to understand this code clearly, please help. I can't figure out how this program keep track of how many number has given in responses array. 
I don't understand what's going on the for loop and specially this line ++frequency[responses[answer]];

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define RESPONSE_SIZE 40
    #define FREQUENCY_SIZE 11

    int main(void)
    {
        int answer; /* counter to loop through 40 responses */
        int rating; /* counter to loop through frequencies 1-10 */

        /* initialize frequency counters to 0 */

        int frequency[FREQUENCY_SIZE] = {0};

        /* place the survey responses in the responses array */

        int responses[RESPONSE_SIZE] = {1,2,6,4,8,5,9,7,8,10,1,6,3,8,6,10,3,8,2,7,6,5,7,6,8,6,7,5,6,6,5,6,7,5,6,4,8,6,8,10};

        /* for each answer, select value of an element of array responses
        and use that value as subscript in array frequency to determine element to increment */

        for(answer = 0 ; answer < RESPONSE_SIZE; answer++){
            ++frequency[responses[answer]];
        }

        printf("%s%17s\n", "Rating", "Frequency");

        /* output the frequencies in a tabular format */
        for(rating = 1; rating < FREQUENCY_SIZE; rating++){
            printf("%6d%17d\n", rating, frequency[rating]);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Any C tutorial should explain array access. This code just uses the value from one array as the index into the other. The comment pretty much says that as well. May or may not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`++frequency[responses[answer]]` is a dense way of writing

```
int r = response[answer];
frequency[r] = frequency[r] + 1;
```

with the caveat that `frequency[r]` is only evaluated once.

So, if `answer` equals `0`, then `responses[answer]` equals `1`, so we add `1` to `frequency[1]`.

**Edit**

The following table shows what happens to `frequency` through the loop (old value => new value):

```
answer    response[answer]    frequency[response[answer]]
------    ----------------    ---------------------------
     0                   1           frequency[1]: 0 => 1
     1                   2           frequency[2]: 0 => 1
     2                   6           frequency[6]: 0 => 1
     3                   4           frequency[4]: 0 => 1
   ...                 ...           ...
    10                   1           frequency[1]: 1 => 2
```

etc.

Comment: int responses[RESPONSE_SIZE] = {1,2,6,4,8,5,9,7,8,10,1,6,3,8,6,10,3,8,2,7,6,5,7,6,8,6,7,5,6,6,5,6,7,5,6,4,8,6,8,10};

if answer equals 0, then responses[answer] equals 1, so we add 1 to frequency[1]. Later we again encounter number 1 in 10th position of responses. 

So then if answer equals 10, then responses[answer] equal 1, so again we add 1 to frequency[1]. Thus value in index frequency[1] becomes 2 ? right ?

Comment: Clearly understood! Thanks, you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(answer = 0 ; answer < RESPONSE_SIZE; answer++){
    ++frequency[responses[answer]];     //  <---
}
```

This above loop just counts the number of times a number appear in array `responses` and that is stored at that number's index in array `frequency`. This line does that in first loop -

```
 ++frequency[responses[answer]];
```

So , it increments value at index `responses[answer]` of array `frequency`.

Lets say `responses[answer]` has value `1` , then value at index `1` of array `frequency` is incremented.

Second `for` loop is just for output as mentioned.